# How to get difference values between an array of values and array of object using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two array as

```
a1 = ['test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test3@gmail.com'];
a2 = [{email: 'test1@gmail.com'},{email: 'test2@gmail.com'}];
```

Now I want to get difference between these two array mentioned above as

```
resultDifference = ['test3@gmail.com'];
```

How to achieve this difference result by using lodash only.

Comment: what do you mean by difference here

Comment: difference mean the set of email value which does not exist in array a2 when we compare the value of array a1. @cmgchess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add what you have tried to your post

```
const a1 = ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "test3@gmail.com"];
const a2 = [{ email: "test1@gmail.com" }, { email: "test2@gmail.com" }];

const ans = _.difference(
  a1,
  a2.map((a) => a.email)
);
```

Comment: I had tried const resultDifference = _.difference(a1,a2.email)); but I was getting the same array a1 as a result, Which is wrong obviously. But As you suggested to use map method, now I am getting correct result as wanted. @anttud